# Type out text over Remote Assistance

Tags: powershell, intune, remote-assistance

I am trying to type out a String over Windows Remoteassistanse, but my PowerShell Script doesn't work.

It works in the normal editor and Teams Remotecontrol.

```
$text = "HI"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

$wshell.SendKeys($text)
```

Does Remote Assinstance block something like this for security reasons or is there just a better way?

It doesn't have to be in PowerShell by the way I also wrote the a script with Python which had the same problem.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Try adding a return to the message : $text = "HI`n"

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your idea sadly this appraoch didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!

The script didn't run because it couldn't access the window.
**Running the script as administrator fixed the issue for me.**